# How to create a right click event handler in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I would please like to know how to display a context menu when you right click on the window.

Here is my code so far :

```
private void ShowContextMenu_RightClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolStripMenuItem5.Visible = true;
}
private void toolStripMenuItem5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hi there this is my 3rd app which is *animation*.", "Programmed by D & K");
}
```

Comment: It is automatic and doesn't require code.  Drop a ContextMenuStrip from the toolbox onto the form and add menu items.  Set the form's ContextMenuStrip property.  An introductory book or decent tutorial on Winforms can save you (and us) a *lot* of time.

Comment: @HansPassant no... just dragging and drop does not attach menu with form... it just create the menu object in form.. how it should know where you want to attach the context menu?? so if you want to attach it with form in form.cs file you have to attach the created context menu with form,  check the below I answered clearly..

Comment: The designer already auto-generates the code you wrote by hand.  It won't make the same mistake you made, it ensures the CMS is automatically disposed when the window is closed.  This is definitely the kind of code that's best not written, always favor the designer when it can get the job done as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in form cs file you can attach your context menu like this..

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Create right click menu..
        ContextMenuStrip s = new ContextMenuStrip();

        // add one right click menu item named as hello           
        ToolStripMenuItem hello = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        hello.Text = "Hello";

        // add the clickevent of hello item
        hello.Click += hello_Click;

        // add the item in right click menu
        s.Items.Add(hello);

        // attach the right click menu with form
        this.ContextMenuStrip = s;
    }

    void hello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello Clicked");
    }
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it works. Why only void and not private void or public void.

Comment: where??? for **hello_click** method?? here you can try as per the need.. i just created default thats it..

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK there is no direct RightClick event in winforms. You can use the mousedown event to achieve this

```
  private void toolStripButton1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hi there this is my 3rd app which is *animation*.", "Programed by D & K");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MouseDown`. Then you can get the clicked button with `e.Button` and the coordinates with `e.X` and `e.Y`.

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Button.ToString() + " " + e.X + " " + e.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a ContextMenuStrip control to the form (note, it does not display on the form but is instead shown at the bottom of the designer).
In the form's ContextMenuStrip property, choose the name of the ContextMenuStrip control you just added to the form.
That's it. HansPassant stated this in a comment to the question but I think it is being overlooked.
The ContextMenuStrip property is a property of many UI controls that you would use the same technique for.